# Проверка строки на наличие недопустимых символов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мы получаем строку из файла "input"
Надо проверить на наличие недопустимых символов
В качестве первого символа могут выступать только русские буквы (большие и маленькие)
Последующие символы могут быть русскими буквами (маленькими), знаками препинания (список знаков: !?:;"'., ), пробелами или цифрами

Придумал алгоритм (пока что только на словесном)
Если первый символ не относится к русским буквам, то выводим "текст некорректен"
Иначе если все символы начиная со второго относятся к знакам или буквам, то выводим "текст корректен"
Иначе выводим "текст некорректен"

Вопрос в том, как можно создать "множество" символов и "множество" знаков(препинания, чисел и пробелов)?

Comment: Списки из Питона вас чем не устраивают?

Comment: someList = []
Неплохо бы сначала спрашивать у поисковика...

Comment: Привели бы пример для корректного текста и некорректного )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приведу пример проверки через регулярные выражения:

```
import re


def is_ok(text):
    match = re.match("""^[а-яА-ЯёЁ][а-яё0-9 !?:;"'.,]+$""", text)
    return bool(match)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ok_texts = ['Привет;', 'привет;', 'привет, пока;', 'привет? пока;', 'привет 123;']
    for text in ok_texts:
        print(is_ok(text), text)

    print()

    not_ok_texts = ['прИвет;', '1привет;', 'hello;', 'прИВет (пока);', 'Привет (пока);']
    for text in not_ok_texts:
        print(is_ok(text), text)
```

Консоль:

```
True Привет;
True привет;
True привет, пока;
True привет? пока;
True привет 123;

False прИвет;
False 1привет;
False hello;
False прИВет (пока);
False Привет (пока);
```

---

Спасибо *Игорь Игоряныч* за примеры!

Comment: Через регулярки даже по моему удобнее.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, в регулярках все прекрасно, кроме самих регулярок :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import string


first_let, *others = input()

rus_lower = set('аоуыэяеёюибвгдйжзклмнпрстфхцчшщ')
rus_upper = set('АОУЫЭЯЕЁЮИБВГДЙЖЗКЛМНПРСТФХЦЧШЩ')
# разрешенные символы
symbols = set('!?:;"., ').union(string.digits)

if first_let not in rus_lower.union(rus_upper):
    print('Первый символ введен не корректно')
if set(others).difference(set.union(rus_lower, symbols)):
    print('Введен не корректный символ')
```

Корректный ввод:

```
Привет;
привет;
привет, пока;
привет? пока;
привет 123;
```

Не корректный ввод:

```
прИвет;
1привет;
hello;
прИВет (пока);
Привет (пока);
```

Comment: В такой записи `set('а, о, у, ы, э, я,...` во множестве будут также символы ` ` и `,`. Так нужно?

Comment: @gil9red поправил, но эти символы все равно входили в разрешенные ))